# Switch Statement for Field Value

Tags: event-handling, switch-statement, acumatica

I am trying to set up a customization that will dynamically display values in a series of fields using a switch statement.

If we focus on one field I have a String List

```
public static class SMSPlans
{
 public const string A = "A";
 public const string B = "B";
 public const string C = "C";
 public const string Z = "Z";
}

[PXDBString(2, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXDefault(SMSPlans.Z)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "SMS Plan Selected")]
[PXStringList(
 new string[]
 {
 SMSPlans.A,
 SMSPlans.B,
 SMSPlans.C,
 SMSPlans.Z
 },
 new string[]
 {
 "Plan A",
 "Plan B",
 "Plan C",
 "No Text Plan"
 })]
```

I would like to when this field is set to any one of the allowable values populate a series of fields with corresponding fixed values as shown in the image below (0 is default value currently would show up if any plan is selected)

[image: Sample Image]

I planned on using the formula functions and using a switch statement to set my desired value that would look like

```
[PXFormula(null,typeof(Switch<Case<Where<Current<UsrMPSMSPlanSelected, Equal<SMSPlans.A>>,0>))]
```

I am stuck however on:

1. How I need to use the _RowSelect() or other event handlers
2. What if any value would be stored in the database for these fields assigned by the switch statment
3. finally is this switch structured correctly as it is not currently working

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you have a few ways to handle this.

1) With PXFormula attribute tags - your Switch definition is mostly correct in the sample above but depending on where you have it the PXFormula definition itself is incorrect.    What I would do is put the PXFormula tag on the fields that need to be updated.

For example, if your field is UsrMinText use the following:

```
[PXFormula(typeof(Switch<Case<Where<UsrMPSMSPlanSelected,Equal<SMSPlans.A>>,{value if true},{value if false or more case statements}))]
```

2) Personally for this type of customization I would use an actual event method in the BLC to do this.   A good example of this is in the help guide for the events.

```
protected void Batch_ManualStatus_FieldUpdating(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
    Batch batch = (Batch)e.Row;
    if (batch != null && e.NewValue != null)
    {
        switch ((string)e.NewValue)
        {
        case "H":
            batch.Hold = true;
            batch.Released = false;
            batch.Posted = false;
            break;
        case "B":
            batch.Hold = false;
            batch.Released = false;
            batch.Posted = false;
            break;
        case "U":
            batch.Hold = false;
            batch.Released = true;
            batch.Posted = false;
            break;
        case "P":
            batch.Hold = false;
            batch.Released = true;
            batch.Posted = true;
            break;
        }
   }
}
```

In either method, the value that will be stored in the database is whatever you specify in either the {True}/{False} values for PXFormula or the values specified in the actual switch methods.

One thing to remember is field order in the DACS is important.   I'd read through the training information and help guides for more information on this.